# Python ImportError: No module named ext

Tags: python-2.7, vagrant

When i running my code I am getting following error saying `ImportError: No module named ext`

Code sample causing error

```
import module.model
module.model.dropdb(input)
module.model.createdb(input)
```

The trace back as follows

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "module/models/__init__.py", line 54, in drop_db
    drop_db_with_migrations(quiet)
  File "module/models/__init__.py", line 31, in drop_db_with_migrations
    from module.app import db
  File "module/app.py", line 42, in <module>
    app.jinja_env.add_extension('hamlpy.ext.HamlPyExtension')
  File "/vagrant-dev/opt/dev_virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Jinja2
-2.6-py2.7.egg/jinja2/environment.py", line 288, in add_extension
    self.extensions.update(load_extensions(self, [extension]))
  File "/vagrant-dev/opt/dev_virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Jinja2
-2.6-py2.7.egg/jinja2/environment.py", line 75, in load_extensions
    extension = import_string(extension)
  File "/vagrant-dev/opt/dev_virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Jinja2
-2.6-py2.7.egg/jinja2/utils.py", line 213, in import_string
    return getattr(__import__(module, None, None, [obj]), obj)
ImportError: No module named ext
```

Comment: You're probably just missing some package that provides whatever `ext` is.

Comment: I've checked `pip install -r requirements.txt` and all requirements are satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in your Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  -- SNIP --
  File "module/app.py", line 42, in <module>
    app.jinja_env.add_extension('hamlpy.ext.HamlPyExtension')
  -- SNIP --
ImportError: No module named ext
```

Jinja2 uses the dunder import mechanism `__import__`(some_package_name_string). It's unable to find a subpackage `ext` in your `hamlpy` package.